# Spread types may only be created types error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, select, checkbox

I need your help. I follow this code sandbox [Codesanbox selectallcheckbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectallcheckbox-ev5l6?file=/src/App.js) to implement select all functionality but encountered error `Spread types may only be created from object types.` Already followed to code but I don't know where I went wrong. Here is my current code:

Retrieve data from api:

```
    const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    return await api
      .get("/admin-reports/users")
      .then((res) => {
        setDataList(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Select All handler:

```
    const selectAll = (e: any) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    if (name == "selectAll") {
      let checkedData = dataList.map((d) => {
        return { ...d, isChecked: checked };
      });
      setDataList(checkedData);
    }
  };
```

Include sample data, console logging inside map:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Gonna need some more details on the error. I would assume that in the selectAll function the error starts with the `return {...d, isChecked: checked}` this would be cause by `d` not being an object {} - it could be a array []

Comment: @J.Cutshall Hi Sir, updated the question and added sample data :)